# How to show multiple alerts in the same view (struct) Xcode swiftUI Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

He I have made an change password view in Xcode but the alerts one of them don't work.

here is my swiftUI code

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

extension String {
    static func myNotEqual(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool {
        return lhs.range(of: rhs, options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}

struct ResetPasswordView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var emailID: String = ""
    @State var ResetPassword: Bool = false
    @State var OldPassword: String = ""
    @State var NewPassword: String = ""
    @State var showError: Bool = false
    @State var errorMessage: String = ""
    @State var isLoading: Bool = false
    @State var showAlert = false
    @State var showPasswordMismatchAlert: Bool = false
    @State var showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            Text("Reset Your Password")
                .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                .hAlign(.leading)
                .padding(.top, -220)
                .padding(.leading, 14)
            
            Text("Even If Your Password Is Wrong, There Will Be Sent a Link to Change Your Password To Your Current Email")
                .font(.title3)
                .hAlign(.leading)
                .padding(.top, -190)
                .padding(.leading, 15)
            VStack{
                
                TextField("Email", text: $emailID)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .textContentType(.none)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                    .border(1, .gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .hAlign(.center)
                    .padding(.leading, 1)
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .padding(.top, -20)
                
                SecureTextField(text: $OldPassword)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .border(1, .gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .hAlign(.center)
                    .padding(.leading, 1)
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .padding(.top, -10)
                
                Secure2TextField(text: $NewPassword)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .border(1, .gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .hAlign(.center)
                    .padding(.leading, 1)
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .padding(.top, -10)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                Group{
                    Text("• 7 characters")
                        .padding(.leading, -83)
                        .foregroundColor(self.requirements[0] ? .green : .red)
                    Text("• 1 number")
                        .padding(.leading, -83)
                        .foregroundColor(self.requirements[1] ? .green : .red)
                    Text("• 1 special character(! @ # $ % ^ *)")
                        .padding(.leading, -0)
                        .foregroundColor(self.requirements[2] ? .green : .red)
                    
                    
                    
                }
                .padding(.leading, -100)
                
                Button("Change Password", action: changePassword)
                    .hAlign(.center)
                    .fillView(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .white : .black)
                    .padding(.leading, 1)
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .padding(.top, -10)
                    .disableWithOpacity(NewPassword == "" || emailID == "" || OldPassword == "" || requirements[0] == false || requirements[1] == false || requirements[2] == false)
                
                Button("Back to Previous Page"){
                    dismiss()
                }
                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                .font(.callout)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .tint(.black)
            }
        }
        
        .alert(isPresented: $showPasswordMismatchAlert){
                    Alert(title: Text("Wrong Password or Email"), message: Text("Try Again"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
        
        .alert(isPresented: $showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert){
                    Alert(title: Text("Done"), message: Text("All Changes Were Made"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
    }
    
    func changePassword() {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailID, password: OldPassword) { _, error in
            if error != nil {
            showPasswordMismatchAlert = true
            }else{
                Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: NewPassword)
                
                showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert = true
                
                let userUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                let databaseRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userUID!)
                let updatePassword = NewPassword
                databaseRef.setData(["passwordLog": updatePassword], merge: true) { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error updating document: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Email updated successfully")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct SecureTextField: View {
        
        @State private var isSecureField: Bool = true
        @Binding var text: String
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack{
                if isSecureField {
                    SecureField ("Current Password", text: $text)
                }else{
                    TextField("Current Password", text: $text)
                }
            }.overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                Image(systemName: isSecureField ? "eye.slash": "eye")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isSecureField.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct Secure2TextField: View {
        
        @State private var isSecureField: Bool = true
        @Binding var text: String
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack{
                if isSecureField {
                    SecureField ("New Password", text: $text)
                }else{
                    TextField("New Password", text: $text)
                }
            }.overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                Image(systemName: isSecureField ? "eye.slash": "eye")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isSecureField.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var requirements: Array<Bool> {
        [
            NewPassword.count >= 7,             // Minimum Length
            NewPassword != "[0-9]",             // One Number
            NewPassword != ".*[^A-Za-z0-9].*"   // One Special Character
        ]
    }
    
    func VerifyPassword(){
        showAlert = true
        isLoading = true
        Task{
            do{
                try await Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: emailID)
                print("email sent")
                try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailID, password: OldPassword)
                print("Pasword Worked")
                changePassword()
            }catch{
                await setError(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    //MARK: Displaying Errors VIA Alert
    func setError(_ error: Error)async{
        //MARK: UI Must be Updated on Main Thread
        await MainActor.run(body: {
            errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            showError.toggle()
            isLoading = false
        })
    }
}


struct ResetPasswordView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ResetPasswordView()
    }
}
```

I have tryd removing the $showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert alert and if I did that the $showPasswordMismatchAlert alert works and the other way around. so the problem I think is that I can't have two alerts at the same time in one view (struct) please help me

Comment: You don’t need multiple. Use the one with “error” in the initializer and load it with the proper error/message.

Comment: that wouldn't work. If I did that it wouldn't show a success message. o and I solved it. see below

Comment: That is a fine solution too but my solution would work too. It is more versatile, you would get an actual error message.

Comment: aaaahh yes, But that wasn't what I asked. I asked for how to show multiple alerts. And the error would be for a user that probably wouldn't even understand the error so I just wanted to get a fail and a success alert

Comment: Got it so just ignore if there is no network access or firebase is down, etc. I didn’t write an answer in the first place it is just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the code,
the problem was that I couldn't show two separate alerts in the same struct (view) so I made one alert that if is if showPasswordMismatchAlert = true he shows the mismatch alert and if is showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert = true he shows the success alert and I did the showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert = true thing in the error Handlemend of my function so if there was an error with "Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailID, password: CurrentPassword)" he shows show showPasswordMismatchAlert = true and showAlert = true and if he doesn't have an error he shows showPasswordMismatchAlert = false showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert = true showAlert = true (why the false well if the user has had an error and now tries again and the showPasswordMismatchAlert wood still be true he wood show showPasswordMismatchAlert) the error Handlemend shit of my function is

```
    func changePassword() {
                Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailID, password: CurrentPassword) { _, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: emailID)
                        showPasswordMismatchAlert = true
                        showAlert = true
                    } else {
                        Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: emailID)
                        Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: NewPassword)
                        showPasswordMismatchAlert = false
                        showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert = true
                        showAlert = true
    
                        let userUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                        let databaseRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userUID!)
                        let updatePassword = ["passwordLog": NewPassword]
    
                        databaseRef.updateData(updatePassword)
    
                        let updateEmailLog = ["userEmail": emailID]
                        databaseRef.updateData(updateEmailLog)
                    }
                }
            }
```

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

extension String {
    static func myNotEqual(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool {
        return lhs.range(of: rhs, options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}

struct ResetPasswordView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var emailID: String = ""
    @State var ResetPassword: Bool = false
    @State var CurrentPassword: String = ""
    @State var NewPassword: String = ""
    @State var showError: Bool = false
    @State var errorMessage: String = ""
    @State var isLoading: Bool = false
    @State var showAlert = false
    @State var showPasswordMismatchAlert: Bool = false
    @State var showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            Text("Reset Your Password")
                .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                .hAlign(.leading)
                .padding(.top, -260)
                .padding(.leading, 14)
            
            Text("If You Don't Know Your Password Don't Worry,\nThere Will Be Sent a Reset Link to Your Email, Regardless of if You Put in The Right Password")
                .hAlign(.leading)
                .padding(.top, -230)
                .padding(.leading, 14)
        
            VStack{
                
                TextField("Email", text: $emailID)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .textContentType(.none)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                    .border(1, .gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .hAlign(.center)
                    .padding(.leading, 1)
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .padding(.top, -100)
                
                SecureTextField(text: $CurrentPassword)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .border(1, .gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .hAlign(.center)
                    .padding(.leading, 1)
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .padding(.top, -60)
                
                Secure2TextField(text: $NewPassword)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .border(1, .gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .hAlign(.center)
                    .padding(.leading, 1)
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .padding(.top, -20)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                Group{
                    Text("• 7 characters")
                        .padding(.leading, -83)
                        .foregroundColor(self.requirements[0] ? .green : .red)
                    Text("• 1 number")
                        .padding(.leading, -83)
                        .foregroundColor(self.requirements[1] ? .green : .red)
                    Text("• 1 special character(! @ # $ % ^ *)")
                        .padding(.leading, -0)
                        .foregroundColor(self.requirements[2] ? .green : .red)
                    
                    
                    
                }
                .padding(.leading, -100)
                
                Button("Change Password", action: changePassword)
                    .hAlign(.center)
                    .fillView(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .white : .black)
                    .padding(.leading, 1)
                    .padding(.all, 10)
                    .padding(.top, -10)
                    .disableWithOpacity(NewPassword == "" || emailID == "" || CurrentPassword == "" || requirements[0] == false || requirements[1] == false || requirements[2] == false)
                
                Button("Back to Previous Page"){
                    dismiss()
                }
                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                .font(.callout)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .tint(.black)
            }
        }
        
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                    if showPasswordMismatchAlert {
                        return Alert(title: Text("Wrong Password or Email"), message: Text("Try Again"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                    } else if showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert {
                        return Alert(title: Text("Your Password is Changed"), message: Text("There is an email sent to your current email if you want to change it back within the next hour"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                    } else {
                        return Alert(title: Text("Not Right"), message: Text("something is wrong contact the develeper at ziya@ziyaxservers.nl"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                    }
                }
    }
    
    func changePassword() {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailID, password: CurrentPassword) { _, error in
                if error != nil {
                    Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: emailID)
                    showPasswordMismatchAlert = true
                    showAlert = true
                } else {
                    Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: emailID)
                    Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: NewPassword)
                    showPasswordMismatchAlert = false
                    showPasswordChangeSuccessAlert = true
                    showAlert = true
                    
                    let userUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                    let databaseRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userUID!)
                    let updatePassword = ["passwordLog": NewPassword]
                    
                    databaseRef.updateData(updatePassword)
                    
                    let updateEmailLog = ["userEmail": emailID]
                    databaseRef.updateData(updateEmailLog)
                }
            }
        }
    
    struct SecureTextField: View {
        
        @State private var isSecureField: Bool = true
        @Binding var text: String
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack{
                if isSecureField {
                    SecureField ("Current Password", text: $text)
                }else{
                    TextField("Current Password", text: $text)
                }
            }.overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                Image(systemName: isSecureField ? "eye.slash": "eye")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isSecureField.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct Secure2TextField: View {
        
        @State private var isSecureField: Bool = true
        @Binding var text: String
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack{
                if isSecureField {
                    SecureField ("New Password", text: $text)
                }else{
                    TextField("New Password", text: $text)
                }
            }.overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                Image(systemName: isSecureField ? "eye.slash": "eye")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isSecureField.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var requirements: Array<Bool> {
        [
            NewPassword.count >= 7,             // Minimum Length
            NewPassword != "[0-9]",             // One Number
            NewPassword != ".*[^A-Za-z0-9].*"   // One Special Character
        ]
    }
    
    
}


struct ResetPasswordView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ResetPasswordView()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip @Yunnosch is it good this way (forgive me for my English it's pretty bad)